# How can you change on runtime the header text from a RadGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

How can you change on runtime the header text from a Telerik.WinControls .UI.RadGridView? The year in header text has to be dynamically...

This is what I want

[image]

This is the result what I see (the years are not shown)...

[image]

```
        private void gvMyGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name.Contains("_Current"))
                {
                    e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.HeaderText += "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                }
                else if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name.Contains("_Prior"))
                {
                    e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.HeaderText += "\r\n" + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString();
                }
...
}
```

Comment: Your code does not look bad. Can you tell us what is the problem with your code?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `"\r\n"` part? does it show the year after the month?

Comment: \r\n is a part what I need. Because I want to place the year on the next row in the header. I have set WrapText = true.

Comment: Try adding this lines `if (e.CellElement is GridHeaderCellElement)
    {
        e.CellElement.TextWrap = true;
    }`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution. I do not place it in the Event. But I call the method in the constructor. The column header is drawn before the Event CellFormatting.

```
    public MyFormView()
    {
        ...
        InitColumnHeaders();
    }

    private void InitColumnHeaders()
    {
        foreach (GridViewDataColumn column  in gvMyGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Name.Contains("_Current"))
            {
                column.HeaderText += "\r\n" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            }
            else if (column.Name.Contains("_Prior"))
            {
                column.HeaderText += "\r\n" + (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```